# Как убрать scrollbar в окне WebView

Tags: java, android, css, webview

WebView загружает сайт на котором scrollbar не нужен. Через css убрать scrollbar на мобильной версии сайта невозможно. Есть ли способ убрать его используя редактирования WebView окна с помощью java?

Comment: opacity пробовали ?

Comment: Работает только в ПК-версии хрома. Нужно забрать скроллбар на версии для мобильных устройств. CSS, скорее всего, на это не способен.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll Попробуйте это

Answer (score 0):

а само прокручивание-то нужно? если нет, поставьте `overflow:hidden`. если нужен, гуглите в сторону стилизации скроллбаров. Пример для хрома, который сделает скроллбар невидимым:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Прокручивание нужно. Вся стилизация скроллбара, которую я пробовал, работает только в ПК-версии хрома. Предложенную вами стилизацию в том числе. ```-webkit-appearance: none``` или ```background: transparent``` не работают.